# LINQ to SQL and N-Tier layering

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, linq, n-tier-architecture

My experience has made me more accustomed to the following structure in my programs.  Let's say it is a .NET WPF application.  You create a WPF project, a Business Logic project (Class Library), a Data Access project (Class Library), and an Entities project (Class Library).  The WPF project goes through the Business Logic Layer to the Data Access Layer.  The Entities are lightweight DTOs and can flow freely from layer to layer.

My question is this.  I like LINQ to SQL entities, except if I use it to create my entities, I not only wind up with a straight table to entities relationship, it also puts my Entities in my Data Access project and forces my UI project to have a reference to my Data Access project.  Granted, I can make my DataContext internal (which I think it should be by default anyhow), except my DTOs are still in my Data Access project and it still forces my UI project to have a reference to my Data Access project.

Am I missing something here or is there another way to extricate my DTOs with LINQ to SQL or should I even care?

Comment: You sad your DTO's are in separated project "Entities project". So your UI need reference to Entities project only. Then both DataAccess and UI projects will reference Entities project, without knowing about each other

Comment: I'm not sad about my UI project and my Data Access project not requiring knowledge of how each other work.  I believe this is a good thing.  My UI  project requires no changes, not even in references if the database is switched to MySQL or DB2 instead of SQL Server.  Why should I have to release a new version of the UI to the clients for that?  Of course, everyone has to have a reference to the DTOs.

Comment: So what is your question? `UI` have abstraction of needed behavior and data. `Businees logic` will implement `UI`'s abstractions and have abstractions of needed data services. `Data access` will implement `Businees logic`'s service abstractions. `DTO project` implement `UI`'s data model abstractions and if possible used by `Data access` as entities or you create some mapping between `Data access`'s entities and data model abstractions. In this way your dependency flow will be from high level layer to the details layer, where details layer can be changed more easiily

Comment: "My question is this. I like LINQ to SQL entities, except if I use it to create my entities, I not only wind up with a straight table to entities relationship, it also puts my Entities in my Data Access project and forces my UI project to have a reference to my Data Access project."  Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

If we follow a Dependency inversion principle

> - High level modules should not depend upon low-level modules. Both    should depend upon abstractions.
> - Abstractions should never depend upon details. Details should depend    upon abstractions.

So in your case `UI` and `Business logic` should not depend upon `Data access`.  Abstracted entities should never depend upon details of `LINQ to SQL`

Then we start design our application from high level layers

1 Create **Project of entities abstractions**

```
public interface ICustomer
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}
```

2 Create **Project business logic abstractions** used by UI project

```
public interface ICustomerService
{
    List<ICustomer> LoadTop50();
}
```

3 Create **UI project**

3.1 Create UI logic which use `ICustomer` and `ICustomerService` for showing person information

*Notice: UI depends only on abstractions and have no knowledge about other layers.*

4 Create **Business project**

4.1 Create `DataAccess` abstraction for fetching data

```
    namespace Business.DataAccessAbstractions
    {
        public interface ICustomerDataAccess
        {
            List<ICustomer> Load(int topAmount);
        }
    }
```

4.2 Implement `ICustomerService` which use abstractions of `ICustomerDataAccess`

```
public class CustomerService : ICustomerService
{
    private DataAccessAbstractions.ICustomerDataAccess _dataAccess;

    public CustomerService(DataAccessAbstractions.ICustomerDataAccess dataAccess)
    {
        _dataAccess = dataAccess;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ICustomer> LoadTop50()
    {
        const int TOP_NUMBER = 50;
        return _dataAccess.Load(TOP_NUMBER);
    }
}
```

*Notice: `Business` project create abstractions for data access. And implement abstractions, which UI will use for showing data.*

5 Create **DataAccess project**

5.1 Create entities with `LINQ to SQL`.

5.2 Implement `Business.DataAccessAbstractions.ICustomerDataAccess` interface.

5.2.1 Make entities, generated by `LINQ to SQL`, implement `ICustomer`

```
    [Table(Name="dbo.Customer")]
    public partial class Customer : INotifyPropertyChanging, 
                                    INotifyPropertyChanged, 
                                    ICustomer
    {
        private int _Id;

        [Column(Storage="_Id", 
                AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert, 
                DbType="Int NOT NULL IDENTITY", 
                IsPrimaryKey=true, 
                IsDbGenerated=true)]
        public int Id
        {
            get
            {
                return this._Id;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._Id != value))
                {
                    this.OnIDChanging(value);
                    this.SendPropertyChanging();
                    this._Id = value;
                    this.SendPropertyChanged("Id");
                    this.OnIDChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You need only add `ICustomer` to the list of implemented interfaces. Or create/generate some "mapping logic" which convert entities generated by `LINQ to SQL` to the instances which will impelement `ICustomer`. I found that adding `ICustomer` was easiest way for this sample.

*Notice: `DataAccess` project have dependencies only on abstractions which is implemented by using `LINQ to SQL`*

6 Create **Main project** which will compound all dependencies together and launch your UI.

*Notice: This project will have all references needed for your application to work properly.*

**Summary**

With this approach you UI will not depend on details of `LINQ to SQL`.

With this approach you can freely modify your implementation of `DataAccess` until modifications will not break high level abstractions.

Of course if you decide to add new data field for Customer, which you want use in UI, then you need to modify whole chain of dependencies.